# Oracle reference for C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle via C# but I am missing a reference to make this work:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

The error is of course:

> The type or namespace name 'Oracle' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Since this is the standard error for missing a reference.

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.

I tried to find the reference [online](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) but I can't manage to find a working one. Also is there anything more I need in **C#** to connect to an Oracle database?

Where do I find the right reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the Oracle .Net stuff: [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

This will include some .NET wrapper classes to the underlying Oracle client. If memory serves, they should be placed in GAC so should be easy to find from the VS.NET add references window.

Comment: If they aren't in GAC there is going to be a reference assembly folder somewhere in the Oracle directory structure. Pretty sure they are in the GAC though.

Comment: GAC? Sorry but what does it mean?

Comment: GAC = Global Assembly Cache. Common place where "dll" files are stored. You can browse it in %WINDIR%\assembly. For more info you can contact Google.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: can you elaborate more? please check my question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074742/script-component-missing-oracle-reference

Comment: @dkackman: do we need to register dll also? can u check my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074742/script-component-missing-oracle-reference