# script component missing oracle reference

Tags: c#, oracle, ssis

I try to use script component and insert some data to Oracle database but I face with below issue.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

---

> at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)    at
>   UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)    at
>   UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName,
>   PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32
>   InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32
>   inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

after googling, I thought my problem should be same as [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682001/oracle-reference-for-c-sharp) I copy the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll  from 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

to

C:\Windows\assembly

or

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC

as adviced in the previous link. but again I face with the same issue. would you mind advising me did I miss any part?

I am using SSIS2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is wrong, you should not copy files manually to `C:\Windows\assembly`. Just a note, starting with the .NET Framework 4, the default location for the Global Assembly Cache is `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`

- Either you copy the DLL to folder of your application executable.
- Or add it to GAC (Global Assembly Cache). This is done with tool [gacutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool). I assume every Setup-Tool also provides an option "Add to GAC". You can also use `...\odp.net\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe` and/or `...\odp.net\managed\x86\OraProvCfg.exe` for it.
- There are a few more locations where you can put the DLL (see [Probing the Application Base and Culture Directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies#probing-the-application-base-and-culture-directories)), however the application's root directory is the standard.

Comment: @Wernfired: Tq for your quick reply.
regarding the first point, "Either you copy the dll to the folder of your application executable" => we are talking about SSIS packages, I am testing my application in debug mode, do you expect me to put the dll in where exactly?

Comment: where gacutil,exe is located, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Go to start Menu -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Developer Command Prompt for VS. There you should find it.

Comment: Tq so much, it seems that it is working... I used above VS direction and from developer command prompt run  gacutil.exe /i "c:\program files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"